# Flutter - Widget Test throws "None were found" where widgets do exist

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I tried to test my Flutter app using flutter test like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:fnb/ui/page/standard/login.dart' as app;

void main() {
  group("Login test: ", () {
    testWidgets("Ensure there are 2 text form, and button widget",
        (WidgetTester tester) async {

      app.LoginPage();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(find.byType(TextFormField), findsNWidgets(2));
      expect(find.byKey(Key('Buttonlogin')), findsWidgets);
    });
  });
}
```

The result is i got like this:

```
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "TextFormField" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
  Which: means none were found but one was expected
```

But, when i try to open the page that i want to test, there are the existence of these widget like this:

[image]

So, whats wrong with my test code?

Comment: Mount `LoginPage` inside `await tester.pumpWidget(...)`. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/widget/introduction#4-build-the-widget-using-the-widgettester